# Why is there a syntax error in relation to end label?

Tags: python

I'm new to python (I'm using Python 3.5) and I'm learning about ways to end output. The aim is to get the output all on one line and use space as the end character.

The instruction from the book is to put:

```
for n in range (3)
print('Hurray!' end=' ')
```

... and it should produce:

```
Hurray! Hurray! Hurray!
```

However I'm just getting and error saying invalid syntax. Apparantly it's do do with the 'end' label.

Comment: missing `:` at end of `for` line should be `for n in range (3): print('Hurray!' end=' ')`

Comment: And a comma in the function call.

Comment: Please do pay *close attention* to the syntax in the book. You are missing indentation and the `:` colon, as well as a comma in the `print()` call. The `print()` function call must be indented.

Answer (score 2):

It should be,

```
for n in range (3):
   print('Hurray!', end=" ")
```

Mind the indentation as well. When it comes to next line, it would be 4 space or 1 tab! That would again throw an error if not taken care!

Comment: According to PEP-8 the indentation should be done with spaces.

Comment: True.......and in few editors with the preference settings, it would be taken care by default